# preg_match error message when pressing enter

Tags: php

I have the following code in php, which enables field "news" to get only the characters a-z and numbers 0-9 and space. How can I modify it, so except a-z, 0-9 and space to get "enter"? because when I type enter I get the error message "News field, must only contains a-z, 0-9 characters and spaces"

```
if( preg_match("&[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]&",$_POST['news']) ){
    $errors[]='<font color="#963">News field, must only contains a-z, 0-9 characters and spaces</font>';
} preg_replace("&[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]&","",$_POST['news']);
```

Comment: what do you mean by getting "enter"?

Comment: I have a textbox and I am writting something in it. If I type enter to go a line under, then there is a problem

Comment: oh, you mean newlines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
&[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]&
```

the `\s` should find any type of whitespace, including newlines and spaces. if you only want spaces and newlines (not tabs or other whitespace) you can do `&[^a-zA-Z0-9 \n]&` instead.